# How to append everything under a list index to current?

Tags: python

Not sure what this would be called but I have something like:

```
dict = {
    1: "{} test string 01",
    2: "{} test string 02",
    3: "{} test string 03
}
```

If i wanted to loop through each and concatenate them so that `3:` contains `{} test string 03 {} test string 02 test string01` and `2:` contains `{} test string 02 {} test string 01`, how would I go about doing that?

If the dict only had a few entries it'd be easy, but if the dict contained 20+ items, what's the most efficient way of kind of doing a...backwards recursion (not sure if that's the right term)?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: The contents of dictionaries is unordered, so the output would be somewhat random unless it's sorted (by key value in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` for Python3:

```
import itertools
import operator
import re
dict = {
1: "{} test string 01",
2: "{} test string 02",
3: "{} test string 03"
}
new_dict = {a:' '.join(re.split('(?<=\d\{\})\s(?=test)', b)[::-1]) for a, b in zip(sorted(dict.keys()), sorted(itertools.accumulate(sorted(dict.values(), key=lambda x:int(x[-1])), func=operator.add)))}
```

Output:

```
{1: '{} test string 01', 2: 'test string 02 {} test string 01{}', 3: 'test string 03 test string 02{} {} test string 01{}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
d = {
    1: "{} test string 01",
    2: "{} test string 02",
    3: "{} test string 03"
}

values = list(d.values())
keys = list(d.keys())

d = dict((i , ' '.join(val for val in reversed(values[:i]))) for i in keys)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: '{} test string 01', 2: '{} test string 02 {} test string 01', 3: '{} test string 03 {} test string 02 {} test string 01'}
```